# How to force shodan update scanning and port reports according to new values

Tags: security, nmap, shodan

Hello to this wonderful community. Recently i bought a vps machine to host a website there. i take all the necessary security measures and i am ok. My problem is that shodan finds over than 10 ports open and over than 5 domains assigned and of course, some CVE exploits its probably from previous assigned clients because when i checked it with my nmap and also contact with my service provider we found the only ports open are  80, 443.

I don't want my ip to be black listed like that from previous reports and scans where shodan scanned before me. Any idea how to fix it and force shodan update his stats??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information in Shodan automatically expires after a port has remained closed. It needs to stay closed for multiple checks by the crawlers in order to confirm that it's permanently closed and not a temporary glitch.

Comment: do you know the max duration for example one month?

Comment: Worst case scenario it will take 30 days for information to expire and disappear from the website/ API.